# What are the advantages of the rails community's naming conventions for naming a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, naming-conventions, join

In [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) Ryan Bates mentions that it's a good convention to use words that end in -tion, -ment, or -ship when naming a join model. What are the advantages of this convention?

For instance, what if I had a two models called "Albums" and "Songs" respectively where a song could appear on many albums and an album has many songs? What would be a good name for the join table needed for this? Tracklistingship? Tracklistings?

Comment: does a song really belong to more than one album? pretty sure that'd be a compilation or mixtape

Comment: @AJcodez Yes, a given recording event can belong to multiple albums (and some people care explicitly about such things). That aside, I don't see a meaningful difference between an "album" and a "compilation", but if there *was* one, it seems like a flag/status would suffice.

Comment: @DaveNewton interesting didnt know

Comment: For instance the same recording (or song) of "Like a Rolling Stone" appears on Highway 61 Revisted as well as Greatest Hits Vol. 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is to name it something that makes sense.

Those relationships often end with those endings. The point is to follow *a* convention and be consistent, not necessarily that everything will fit neatly into the same three endings.

To me it sounds like `Tracks`, `AlbumTracks`, etc. If you wanted to follow his idea of making up a word, perhaps `Trackation` or `Trackination` (the process of putting tracks on an album), `Albumship` (like "membership" but with album songs) etc.

Note also that hopefully you don't have models called `Albums` and `Songs`, rather `Album` and `Song`. IMO the clearest relationship is simply `AlbumSongs`, because that's precisely what it is.

You could go a different route altogether and call them `Mixes`, too.

Comment: Thanks Dave. "Tracks" makes a lot of sense to me, although "tracks" are really the songs on an album, so in that sense it's a little confusing. AlbumSongs seems ok to me but Ryan Bates advised against that convention because he said it can get confusing quickly. So, in this case would "Tracklist" be the best? The reason I need a join table is I need to store additional data about the relationship between songs and albums, such as the order that the song appears on the album. Otherwise I'd just use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship for both.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly I think TrackList is fine, I'd probably name the table track_lists. I'm not sure AlbumSongs is confusing, though. I also wouldn't get so hung up on it that progress stopped, either-it's unlikely the cost or possibility of a change will be a gating development issue.

Comment: I ended up going with `albumization`. I tried `track_lists` first, but when I started setting up the relationship it made more sense conceptually to say the album `has_many :songs, :through => :albumization` and also that song `has_many :albums, :through => albumization`. The process of putting the song on an album and placing it in a position on that album is really what this join model is doing. So I think a made up word here makes sense.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly Seems reasonable; it's like trackination but on reflection that's potentially backwards, while yours isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One other advantage of using consistent naming conventions is that there is a pretty good chance you won't be the only one working on the code. By using a consistent naming convention, others who work on your code will have an easier time working on the code. You might also find it easier to maintain, in the sense that you might not touch the code for 6 months and one day come back to it. By having a consistent naming convention, you will be able to understand what you were doing without having to read through all your code.

Comment: Thanks Blaine. That's a good overview of the value of naming conventions. But I guess it's important to keep them in perspective and not use a convention for the sake of following the convention when it doesn't make sense for your specific problem.